# Creating WDM network driver targeting WinXP x64 - where to start?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wdk, wdm

I downloaded Visual Studio Community Edition with all the C++ install options. Then I installed [WDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) targeting WinXP. However it seems like VS can't recognise this and so there is no option in the new project wizard to create an WDM driver.

I was relying on such option because I haven't been creating drivers before and I don't know much about how it happens and which tools am I allowed to use. I hoped VS automated IDE would help me with this.

Any ideas how to start in such case?

EDIT: Maybe community VS version doesn't support creating drivers?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with WDK: It has its own compiler. You can use VS only as text editor. At compile time, open WDK console, and run the corresponding .bat file (for debug/release/x64 etc.).

Comment: Any detailed tutorial maybe?

Comment: Look at `readme` and similar files coming with WDK. Also note that in the past WDK was called DDK. You may find how-to build examples when searching for DDK. For WinXP it is better to download older WDK/DDK version. WDK includes many examples (skeleton projects) for all types of drivers. You can get one and add modifications for your hardware.